# response.send understanding? (hubot-script)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I recently installed hubot and was testing it.

Now I saw sth. I don't understand:

Given this code (part of [hubot-maps](https://github.com/gkoo/hubot-maps) - maps.coffee [file](https://github.com/gkoo/hubot-maps/blob/master/src/maps.coffee))

```
robot.respond /(?:(satellite|terrain|hybrid)[- ])?map( me)? (.+)/i, (msg) ->
mapType  = msg.match[1] or "roadmap"
location = encodeURIComponent(msg.match[3])
mapUrl   = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=" +
            location +
            "&size=400x400&maptype=" +
            mapType +
            "&sensor=false" +
            "&format=png" # So campfire knows it's an image
url      = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" +
           location +
          "&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=73.579623,100.371094&vpsrc=0&hnear=" +
          location +
          "&t=m&z=11"

msg.send mapUrl
msg.send url
```

Why I do get a response like this

[image]

where I get first `url` and then `mapUrl`?

I expect to get `mapUrl` first and then `url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this hubot PR](https://github.com/hubotio/hubot/pull/803), it looks like Hubot runs your `msg.send`s asynchronously, so there is no guaranteed order.

> As a side effect, listeners are now executed asynchronously. Behavior
>   around message.done should remain the same (process until message.done
>   is true).

If you want `mapUrl` before `url`, you can take a look at the send function in the [source code](https://github.com/hubotio/hubot/blob/ea72eba6d1a100870f241204b012b06fefcfb604/src/response.js#L28-L31), which accepts a list of ordered strings.

```
// Public: Posts a message back to the chat source
//
// strings - One or more strings to be posted. The order of these strings
//           should be kept intact.
//
// Returns nothing.
send (/* ...strings */) {
  const strings = [].slice.call(arguments)
  this.runWithMiddleware.apply(this, ['send', { plaintext: true }].concat(strings))
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!! I'm not very pro in JS. I tried just calling msg.sen(mapUrl,url) but get error. Can you help me there?